# Ubuntu Autopilot Openstack Dashboard inaccessible

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

After a successful Autopilot install, I had to recommission nodes in order to reenable ssh.  Since then, the Openstack Dashboard is offline.  The once reachable IP Address for the dashboard is now not reachable.  How do I go about reenabling access to the Openstack Dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

The entire stack is offline.  Will have to recommission and re-run openstack-install.